# copyright symbol getting converted to?

Tags: pdf, joomla, ms-word

I have a word document which I want to convert into a pdf. However, the copyright symbol keeps getting converted as a question mark '?'

So I cannot upload it into Joomla.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you converting the Word document into a pdf?

Comment: I am just using a pdf converter. However, the copyright symbols are converted into spaces in the pdf. When I upload this pdf into Joomla, the spaces get converted back into '?' question mark symbols. How can this be fixed?

Comment: I don't see how this is programming related, it seems you have a problem with your pdf converter.

Answer (score 0):

If you can print the word document out correctly then you should be able to convert it to a PDF file using a PDF printer.

My personal choice of preference is Bullzip which can turn anything to PDF, also to PNG, TIFF and other formats as well. It's very versatile & it's free.

Here's the link to it: http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php

Try it.